# Arquivo Log4net.dll não encontrada

Tags: asp.net

Todas essas dlls estão na pasta bin e foram referenciadas no projeto, o projeto é compilado sem erros:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v12.1, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v12.1, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v12.1, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v12.1.Export, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v12.1, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v12.1.Core, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraEditors.v12.1, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Porém quando executo o sistema (F5) é exibido o seguinte erro (linha 58):

```
Erro de configuração

Descrição: Erro durante o processamento de um arquivo de configuração necessário para o serviço desta solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro e modifique esse arquivo de configuração apropriadamente. 

Mensagem de Erro do Analisador: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Erro de Origem: 


Linha 56:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Linha 57:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
**Linha 58:         <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>**
    Linha 59:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    Linha 60:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

Comment: Não entendo muito disto, mas a mensagem não fala que esta faltando `log4net.dll`, é bem provável que você esteja usado a versão diferente ou algo assim.

Comment: Também não entendo muito bem, no entanto a versão do arquivo **log4net.dll** que está na pasta bin é a msm versão da **linha 58** como no exemplo que consta na pergunta: versão `Version=1.2.10.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que já encontrou a solução, mas para registrar uma possível solução.

Em muitos casos pessoais isso ocorreu por **incompartibilidade de versões**.

**Para o Visual Studio 2015:**

Clique com o botão direito sobre a Solution e vá até **"Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.."**

Na aba **"Installed"** clique sobre o pacote com erro e verifique se em todos os projetos a versão é a mesma.

Answer (score 2):

Sei que a pergunta já faz um tempo que foi respondida, porém uma solução que serviu para mim foi utilizar o gerenciador de pacotes do NuGet para instalação.

Eu precisava da versão 1.2.15 no meu, então instalei no console do VS.

Usar o comando abaixo para a versão 1.2.15:

`Install-Package log4net-1.2.15 -Version 1.2.15`

Segue o link para mais informações: https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net-1.2.15/1.2.15